# Ассоциация программы с собственным типом файла

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, clickonce

Имеется файл программы в виде:

```
[project]
type=MyApp 1.0 project
directory=D:\Папка проекта
Еще какие-то значения.
```

При открытии файла внутри программы (Файл->Открыть проект) всё работает замечательно. Но появилась нужда открывать этот файл двойным щелчком.
С помощью ClickOne создал файл ассоциаций.

Открытие проекта пытаюсь сделать так:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    if (args.Length >= 2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Открыт проект! УРА!");
        OpenProject(args[1]);
    }
}
```

В Program.cs прописано, что принимаются аргументы:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При регистрации с помощью ClickOnce аргументы приходят не в командную строку, а в `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData`:

```
foreach (string arg in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData)
    MessageBox.Show(arg);
```